# Is 0.1 million singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is 0.1 million singular or plural?
Since 0.1 is smaller than 1, shouldn't it be singular?

E.g:

- This: 0.1 million people is above the age of 65.
- or: 0.1 million people are above the age of 65. <--This sounds right, but is it singular?

Comment: *people* ***are***  

And that's all that matters here.

Comment: 0.1 is less than one. 0.1 mililion is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, 0.1 million signifies *how* many people are above 65. The plurality is for *people* which is the noun here. 0.1 million is just a qualifying number, it is neither singular nor plural.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, if you're dealing with countable items, then *anything* other than 1 is plural, and will use the plural form of the verb.

You should also use plural for fractions that are greater than one. You will say *1.5 kilograms*, not 1.5 kilogram. (There seems to be a grey area for fractions less than 1 though; see [this discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110154912/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57224.html)).

Comment: What is less than one here?

Comment: @Kris: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: (belated comment) "less than one" is, in this case, less than one million (0.1 million); however, the accepted answer makes this irrelevant, as the subject is "people", plural, not "million". Thus: "people are". The linked discussion is appropriate if you're talking about less-than-one fractions of something (even a fraction of a million), using "apples" as the subject, eg, "2 apples are...", "1 apple is...", "0.5 apples are..." -- or would it be:  "0.5 apple _is_ ..."? The linked discussion suggests the former is correct.